# Java: String Manipulation

Tags: java, string, uppercase, lowercase

Example strings...

```
bob
mARy
AaRoN
JeREMY
```

Output...

```
Bob
Mary
Aaron
Jeremy
```

I've looked around the internet and found the following code...

```
public String capitalizeFirstLetter(String original){
    if(original.length() == 0)
        return original;
    return original.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + original.substring(1);
```

I know this only capitalizes the first letter of the string, but could I do something like

```
return original.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + original.toLowerCase(1,substring.length);
```

I'm getting caught up on how to make the rest of the letters in the word lower case. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if (original == null || original.isEmpty())
    return original;
String modified = original.toLowerCase();
return Character.toUpperCase(modified.charAt(0)) + modified.substring(1);
```

Comment: +1 For proper prerequisite checking - String must at least be length  1

Answer (score 1):

```
return original.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + original.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```